# How to create a custom function to do unit conversion (e.g between lbs and kg) in R using "if", "else"

Tags: r, function

I'm learning to code in R. So I have to create a function with 2 arguments to do unit conversions (e.g. from lbs to kg and vice versa using "if", "else"), I've been stuck on it for hours.

For now, I managed to write a code to transform kg to lbs and lbs to kg but I don't see how to write a function to group it all together.

```
lbs2kg <- function(mass) {
kg <- mass*0.45
return(kg)
}

kg2lbs <- function(mass) {
lbs <- mass*0.45
return(lbs)
}
```

my goal would be that the the output of `print(f1(1:3, "kg"), digits = 2)` would be :

```
#[1] 2.2 4.4 6.7
```

Comment: The first function should be `kg <- mass/0.45`.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1 = function(mass, unit){
  if(unit == "kg"){
    mass = mass/0.45
  } else {
    mass = mass*0.45
  }
  return(mass)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Even this works: f1 = function(mass, unit){ if(unit == "kg") mass/0.45 else mass*0.45}